# SDL2 virtual pixel size

Tags: resolution, sdl-2

If I let SDL create the window to default dimensions, I get 1024×768, and everything looks normal. If I explicitly create it with dimensions of 1024×768, everything looks normal. But if I explicitly created with dimensions of 512×384, instead of getting a window with less pixels, I get a window in which every pixel is shrunk, but the logical size of the window is still 1024×768. Is this logical size hardwired into SDL2 in some way?

But no! I wanted fewer pixels, not smaller pixels. I want my pixels to still be the size they really are on the screen. If I draw a line from (0,0) to (511, 383) wanted to go the full diagonal extent of my window. What other function do I need to use alongside of SDL_CreateWindow to achieve this result?

1024x768
[image: 1024x768]

[image: 512x384, code assuming that 512x384 is logical window size]

512x384, code assuming that 512x384 is logical window size

Comment: What's your code for creating these windows?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Nelxiost, for provoking me to find my own answer. Here is the key code, omitting error handling code in between:

```
gWindow = SDL_CreateWindow(title, 1024, 768, SCREEN_WIDTH/2, SCREEN_HEIGHT/2, 0);
gRenderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(gWindow, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | 
    SDL_RENDERER_TARGETTEXTURE);
target = SDL_CreateTexture(gRenderer, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_RGBA8888, 
    SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_TARGET, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
```

and here is the corrected last line of the code:

```
target = SDL_CreateTexture(gRenderer, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_RGBA8888,
    SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_TARGET, SCREEN_WIDTH/2, SCREEN_HEIGHT/2);
```

Summary: if you want one logical pixel to equal one physical pixel, create the target texture with the same dimensions as the window.

On the other hand, if you want the logical dimensions of the window to be invariant regardless of the size of the window, create the target texture with those dimensions in all cases.

Comment: Good job figuring it out. To add some input, I believe what you call "logical pixels" are commonly called texels. The term "pixel" always refers to the actual screen pixels. The SDL works with a renderer that takes a texture and maps it onto a window, which means texels only correspond to pixels when the texture and the window are the same size. This is also what happens with "SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN_DESKTOP", if I'm not mistaken.